# Symfony 1.4 I have trouble getting a value of a hidden field

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

When I create a new record, in the action `processForm` I need to get the value of a hidden field called `idmensajes`. This field is a hidden field, auto-incremental and prymary key.
But when I use `getValue ('idmensajes')` the result is empty. Why? How I can get the value of idmensajes in processForm?

Here the code of `processForm`:

```
 protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
  {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {      
          $form_vals = $this->form->getValue('idmensajes');

      $mensajes = $form->save();
      $this->redirect('mensajes/index');
```

In order to view captured values​​, corresponding to two fields, I added:

```
$form_vals1 = $this->form->getValue('idmensajes');
  $form_vals2= $this->form->getValue('cuerpo');


 $this->getUser()->setFlash("val1", $form_vals1);
$this->getUser()->setFlash("val2", $form_vals2);
```

In the view, indexSuccess.php, I add the code:

```
<?php echo 'El valor del Id es:'. $sf_user->getFlash('val1'); ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'El valor de Cuerpo es: '. $sf_user->getFlash('val2'); ?>
```

Then, I view the value of `val2` but the value `val1` is empty.

Here the complete code, with Flash add:

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
  {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {      

      $mensajes = $form->save();

       $form_vals1 = $this->form->getValue('idmensajes');
      $form_vals2= $this->form->getValue('cuerpo');

         $this->getUser()->setFlash("val1", $form_vals1);
        $this->getUser()->setFlash("val2", $form_vals2);  

      $this->redirect('mensajes/index');
```

Comment: can you post code, where you get value?

Comment: @denys281 I add the complete code of my processForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if **idmensajes** exist, and if you can get another field from your form.

Try this:

```
$this->form['idmensajes']->getValue(),
```

**upd**

Try:

```
 $mensajes = $form->save();
 $idmensajes = $mensajes->getIdmenSajec()// or other getter
```

Comment: The same: idmensajes is empty. However, in the view the value exists. When Symfony loading the template indexSuccess.php, I can see the value generated. But at what point Symfony and Doctrine create the value of a field with autoincrement value?

Comment: @JorgeH And can you get other value from your form? Upd answer

Comment: Yes, I can get and see the other fields in the action. For example, with a field text namened Cuerpo, I can get the value and see.

Comment: @JorgeH if works for you second solution from answer(get value after saving)?

Comment: One moment, I'm testing the new solution

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much for your attention and your time. It was a great solution for my problem.
The conclusion is that a hidden field and auto-increment is not in the form, and  must be captured after recording.